# Angular RXJS calling http post request is not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to Angular RXJS, I am trying to add the post to the server, and then get all posts from the server because I am using Server-side pagination.

Could you please let me know why the addPostToServer function is called but the HTTP Post is not! or if you have a better approach to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance

```
 private pageIndexSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
 public pageIndexAction$ = this.pageIndexSubject.asObservable();

 private pageSizeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(6);
 public pageSizeAction$ = this.pageSizeSubject.asObservable();

 private postInsertedSubject = new Subject<Post>();
 postInsertedAction$ = this.postInsertedSubject.asObservable();

  paginatedPosts$ = combineLatest([
    this.pageSizeAction$, 
    this.pageIndexAction$, 
    this.postInsertedAction$.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      tap((post) => {
      let m = this.addPostToServer(post).pipe(tap(res=>console.log('add post to server', res)))
   })), 
  ]).pipe(
    switchMap(([pageSize,pageIndex,post]) => 
    this.http.get<APIResponse<PagedPosts<Post[]>>>(this.APIURL + '/posts', {
      params:
      {
        size: pageSize.toString(),
        page: pageIndex.toString()
      }
    })
   .pipe(
    map((response) => {
      return response.data;
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError),
    ))
    ).pipe(shareReplay(1))


    addPost(post:Post){
      this.postInsertedSubject.next(post);
    }

    addPostToServer(post: Post | string) {
      console.log('Function called but the HTTP is not !')
        return this.http.post<APIResponse<Post>>(
          this.APIURL + '/posts/',
            post
          )
          .pipe(
            map((res) => {
              //not working
            })
          );
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTPClient will not make a call to the server until you subscribe to the Observable, so call to addPostToServer won't send the HTTP request.

You can subscribe to the observable

```js
    addPostToServer(post: Post | string) {
      console.log('Function called but the HTTP is not !')
        return this.http.post<APIResponse<Post>>(
          this.APIURL + '/posts/',
            post
          )
          .subscribe((res) => {
              // get Your result here
          });
      }
```

Or convert it to a promise using lastResultFrom if using RxJs 7 the use async/await

```js
async addPostToServer(post: Post | string) { 
 let result = await lastResultFrom(this.http.post<APIResponse<Post>>(
          this.APIURL + '/posts/',
            post
          ));
}
```

Or use toPromise is using RxJs 6

```js
async addPostToServer(post: Post | string) { 
    let result = await this.http.post<APIResponse<Post>>(
          this.APIURL + '/posts/',
            post
          ).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,Could you please suggest a way to solve it

Comment: I Updated my original answer